# How can I group a column of totals into a set where each set has a maximum

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a collection of records, each record has a total; I want to split the whole collection up into sets, each set can only hold so much (20 in the example).

I have thought about two methods so far and I've shown a simple representation below:

Sets are separate:
[image]

- set1 has the first two since 5+10=15 (the next 12 will put it over 20).
- set2 will have the next two since 12+7=19.

Another Idea I toyed with is just to add a set column onto the source data set:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out an easy way to complete this using formula, if it's easier to complete in VBA I'll then go that route.

Thanks for the help, I've been thinking about this all week and don't even know what to search for.

**Edit: I'm an idiot.

Comment: Are you trying to get it to be broken up in order or most optimally?

Comment: @Raystafarian I'm trying to keep it in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't come up with a formula, but here is a pretty brute force way of doing it:

```
Sub test()

Dim i           As Long, _
    lr          As Long, _
    sumValue    As Long, _
    counter     As Long

lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
counter = 1
For i = 1 To lr
    sumValue = sumValue + Range("A" & i)
        If sumValue <= 20 Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = counter
        Else
            sumValue = 0
            counter = counter + 1
            i = i - 1
        End If
Next i
End Sub
```

For what it's worth, my results were a tad bit different as I calculated 5+10+12 to be greater than 20...

Comment: Thanks for this, I was tempted to do it this way, but I thought I'd just ask if anyone knew how to do this using a formula.

Comment: @Kenny164 formula for what? Identifying the first number of each set?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by browsing through the related section.

```
=IF(A2="a",ROUNDDOWN((B2-1)/20,0)+1,IF(SUMIF($C1:C$2,C1,$B1:B$2)+B2>20,C1+1,C1))
```

[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26102020/100314) to that answer.

I'm going to accept @sous2817's answer because it was the most helpful and would've been the path I took if I went for the VBA approach.

Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 0):

=ROUNDUP(SUM(R5C[-1]:RC[-1])/20,0)
or
=ROUNDUP(SUM(C$5:C5)/20,0)
where the formula starts at D5 and is pulled down.

Comment: P.S. I had to go afk, thanks to anyone who was kind enough to downvote the otherwise equivalent answer because it was copied from the VBE due to language barriers (original: *=KEREK.FEL(SZUM(C$5:C5)/20;0)*).

Answer (score 0):

The described problem can also be solved with a dynamic array solution in newer versions of excel (Office365).

An example for a possible solution could look like this:

[image: screenshot_1]

which uses the following formula for the sets 2-5:

```
=LET(
    rows,$B$5:$B$17,
    vals,$C$5:$C$17,
    excl,$F$5:F$15,
    rows_filt,OFFSET(rows,COUNT(excl),0,COUNT(rows)-COUNT(excl)),
    vals_filt,OFFSET(vals,COUNT(excl),0,COUNT(rows)-COUNT(excl)),
    cumsum,MMULT(N(ROW(vals_filt)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(vals_filt))),vals_filt),
    FILTER(rows_filt,cumsum<=20)
)
```

but to avoid reference to itself, the formula for set 1 is:

```
=LET(
    rows,$B$5:$B$17,
    vals,$C$5:$C$17,
    cumsum,MMULT(N(ROW(vals)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(vals))),vals),
    FILTER(rows,cumsum<=20)
)
```

(also shown in the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNu9H.png))